# Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android

anyone knows why i get this error? I wanted to make a customList for my ListFragment inside my tabbed activity.

Here are all my classes:

ListViewDemoAdapter:

```
public class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
super(context, R.layout.listview_item, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if(convertView == null) {
// inflate the GridView item layout
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
// initialize the view holder
viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
// recycle the already inflated view
viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
// update the item view
ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);
return convertView;
}
/**
* The view holder design pattern prevents using findViewById()
* repeatedly in the getView() method of the adapter.
*
//* @see http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
*/
private static class ViewHolder {
ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvTitle;
TextView tvDescription;
}
}
```

ListViewItem:

```
public class ListViewItem {
public final Drawable icon; // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
public final String title; // the text for the ListView item title
public final String description; // the text for the ListView item description
public ListViewItem(Drawable icon, String title, String description) {
this.icon = icon;
this.title = title;
this.description = description;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ScoutLogFragment.OnScoutLogInteractionListener {

/**
* The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
* fragments for each of the sections. We use a
* {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
* loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
* may be best to switch to a
* {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
*/
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
* The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
*/
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Set up the action bar.
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
// primary sections of the activity.
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

// When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
// tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
// a reference to the Tab.
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
});

// For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
// Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
// the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
// the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
// this tab is selected.
actionBar.addTab(
actionBar.newTab()
.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
.setTabListener(this));
}
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
// When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
// the ViewPager.
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void OnScoutLogInteraction(String id) {

}


/**
* A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
* one of the sections/tabs/pages.
*/
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
// getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
// Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

switch(position){
case 0:
return ScoutLogFragment.newInstance("a","b");
case 1:
return BlankFragment.newInstance("a","b");
case 2:
return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
default:
return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// Show 3 total pages.
return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
switch (position) {
case 0:
return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
case 1:
return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
case 2:
return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
}
return null;
}
}

/**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
/**
* The fragment argument representing the section number for this
* fragment.
*/
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

/**
* Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
* number.
*/
public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
return rootView;
}
}

}
```

DemoFragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.dskupnjak.myapplication.dummy.DummyContent;

/**
* A fragment representing a list of Items.
* <p/>
* <p/>
* Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnScoutLogInteractionListener}
* interface.
*/
public class DemoFragment extends ListFragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private List<ListViewItem> mItems; // ListView items list

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnScoutLogInteractionListener mListener;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static DemoFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
DemoFragment fragment = new DemoFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

/**
* Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
* fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
*/
public DemoFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (getArguments() != null) {
mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
}

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// initialize the items list
mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
Resources resources = getResources();
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.aim),"aim", "aim desc"));
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bebo), "bebo", "bebo desc"));
mItems.add(new ListViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.youtube), "youtube", "youtube desc"));
// initialize and set the list adapter
setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));

/*// TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
List<ScoutLog> scoutLogList = new ArrayList<ScoutLog>();
scoutLogList.add(new ScoutLog("Inhalt der scoutLogList"));
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ScoutLog>(getActivity(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, scoutLogList));*/

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
try {
mListener = (OnScoutLogInteractionListener) activity;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
+ " must implement OnScoutLogInteractionListener");
}
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
mListener = null;
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

if (null != mListener) {
// Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
// fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
mListener.OnScoutLogInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
}
}

/**
* This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
* fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
* to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
* activity.
* <p/>
* See the Android Training lesson <a href=
* "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
* >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
*/
public interface OnScoutLogInteractionListener {
// TODO: Update argument type and name
public void OnScoutLogInteraction(String id);
}

}
```

listViewItem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the parent view - provides the gray listfragment background color -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@color/frame_background"
android:padding="5dp" >
<!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/frame" >
<!-- the icon view -->
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:contentDescription="test"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
<!-- the container view for the title and description -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
<!-- the title view -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
<!-- the description view -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout
```

thats the error i get: (i also tried to input background color to the 3rd relative Layout since i read that this could throw a error but it didnt help)

```
01-16 10:04:24.040 1550-1550/de.dskupnjak.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.dskupnjak.myapplication, PID: 1550
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at de.dskupnjak.myapplication.ListViewDemoAdapter.getView(ListViewDemoAdapter.java:25)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java
```

anyone has a solution?:S

Comment: Is there more of the stacktrace, especially any nested "caused by" exceptions?

Comment: removing "android:textAppearance=" didnt help :( clean up didnt solve it too. Nope thats the full error i get :S